# Import an image in getStaticPaths and get width and height dimensions in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I'm passing a image file name as a string to `getStaticProps`.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const slug = staticProps?.params?.slug as string;
  const { content, data } = getContent(slug);
  const { image } = data;
  const folderPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");
  const file = fs.readFileSync(`${folderPath}/${image}`);
}
```

I need to do one of the following:

1. Pass the image as a prop to the page component in React so that the image src, width and height are all available.
2. Pass the image src, width and height as separate props to the page component.

If I console.log the `file` variable in getStaticProps it shows me `<Buffer ff d8 f...` so it seems the file import has at least partially worked.

Attempting solution 1, if I try to pass the file var directly I get an error:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const slug = staticProps?.params?.slug as string;
  const { content, data } = getContent(slug);
  const { image } = data;
  const folderPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");
  const file = fs.readFileSync(`${folderPath}/${image}`);

  return {
    props: {
      file,
    },
  };
}
```

> 1 of 1 unhandled error Server Error Error: Error serializing `.file`
> returned from `getStaticProps` in "/[slug]". Reason: `object`
> ("[object Uint8Array]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only
> return JSON serializable data types.

Regarding solution 2, I'm not sure how to read the file's dimentions within getStaticProps.

I have a minor preference for solution 1.

Comment: Is there a reason why your images wouldn't just be in the `public` folder of your next.js project? Then you could circumvent this whole loading from disk step and refer to them directly in your JSX

Comment: @Adnan I could put them in the public folder but then I need to manually specify the width and height. I was hoping to automate this step.

Comment: You can put them in public folder, and have getStaticProps fetch the list of height / widths (instead of img data). Map it to filename

Answer (score 0):

As Adnan said it's possible to get the file dimensions in Node in getStaticProps:

```
import sizeOf from "image-size";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const slug = staticProps?.params?.slug as string;
    const { content, data } = getContent(slug);
    const { image } = data;
    
    const folderPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "public");
    const imagePath = `${folderPath}/${image}`;
    const file = fs.readFileSync(`${folderPath}/${image}`);
    
    const { width, height } = sizeOf(file);

    return {
        props: {
            image,
            width,
            height
        },
    };
}
```